# XMLHttpRequest response send to content script to add dynamic icon in DOM according to response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Chrome extension Summary :

1. Get all the urls from google search from content script
2. Store the urls in an array and send it to background script
3. Background script receives array of urls and send POST request to server for all the urls one by one
4. Background script get the response for each url POST request
5. Now background script send the xhr.responseText to content script
6. content script "Receives" the response. responses are in json format
7. NEED HELP: **now I need to compare the response if response [URLfulfills:true/false] is "true" i have add an icon next to url that responded back true and if it is false i have to set another false icon next to url that responded back "false"**

Background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.locs){
        doSearchRequest(request.locs,sender.tab);
    }
 }
);
//Do the search request

function doSearchRequest(data,tab)
{
var length = Object.keys(data).length;
var sites,sitesUrl;
if (length <= 100){
     sites = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).splice(0,50);
     sitesUrl = JSON.stringify(sites);

    doApiRequest(sites, tab);

      if (length > 50){
      sites = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).splice(50,50);
      sitesUrl = JSON.stringify(sites);
      doApiRequest(sites, tab);
    }
    return;
  }
 }

// Do an api request for multiple sites 
var resp;
function doApiRequest(sitesarray, tab)
{
for(var i=0;i<sitesarray.length;i++){  
 var console = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console;
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var p="domain="+sitesarray[i];
  xhr.open("POST","https://api.xxx.com/api/", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
  {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) 
    {
     resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {data: resp}, function(response) {   
     console.log(status,resp);
     });



   }
 }

  xhr.send(p);
```

ContentScript.js

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){       
     if (request.data){
        data = request.data;                      
     //Need to compare the received message [data] to access dom and 
      change icon according to response

     .............
     ...........
    }
});


//If document is ready, find the urls to check

  $(document).ready(function() {      
    (function checkLoop() {
        // Check if search results have  link
        var results = $('#res').find('a');
       if ( $('.yyy').length != results.length) {  
            // Check urls 
            var locs = {};              
            $(results).each(function (i) {                                                     
               var loc = getUrl($(this).attr('href'));
                locs[loc] = loc;
            });
             if(Object.keys(locs).length > 0) {
            // passes grabed urls to background page                    
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({locs: locs}, function(response) {});

            }
        }
        setTimeout(checkLoop, 100);
    })();

});
```

Json formatted API response

```
//my json formatted api response
      {
 "URLfulfills": false,
 "Id": 16,
 "url": {
 "xid": 190,
 "title": "www.facebook.com",
 "description": "social site",
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is inspect the Google search result page and figure out where in the DOM you want to place your icon. Somewhere just next to the search result I would imagine. Additionally you have to request the local URL for the icon from your background script. I assume the icon is already in the same folder as your Chrome extension. Remember to make the icon accessible from the content script by specifying it in the manifest too.

To place the icon into the DOM (from the content script), use jQuery like so: `$(someSearchResult).append('<img src=' + yourIconUrl + ' />');`

If jQuery is not present, you could add it the old fashioned way, or just add jQuery to the DOM first.

Comment: 1. i made the icons accessible in manifest  2.I want to append icon on each url on google search result. 3.What i am not sure is that "how should i compare the response true or false " in content script? and how can i define to place the icon next to each url ?    But can you explain in detail about how  to request the local URL for the icon from  background script ?